# Procmail: Send ticket numbers to an address named "ticket@domain"?

Tags: procmail

I am looking to do the following:

1. User sends an email to `1234@domain`
2. **Procmail recognizes `1234@domain` as an email sent to `ticket+1234@domain`**
3. Procmail recipe handles ticket number and forwards email to the bug tracker

Where **bold** is my current obstacle.

Here is a proof of concept. At this point, the user still has to send the ticket to `ticket+1234@domain` for the email to forward correctly:

```
SUBJECT=`/usr/bin/formail -zx "Subject:"`
:0fhw
* To.*\/([0-9]+)@domain
* MATCH ?? ^\/[0-9]+
|/usr/bin/formail -I "Subject: $SUBJECT (Case $MATCH)"

:0
!tickets@bugtracker
```

**Some context:**

There is one address created, `ticket@domain,` for ticket handling. Currently, a user sends to `ticket+####@domain`, and the Procmail recipe uses `$MATCH` to grab the ticket number that correlates to the bug tracker entry and forwards accordingly. This works.

**What I want to do**:

Prevent auto-completion errors (a user will enter `ticket+` in the recipient field, and the wrong ticket # is auto-completed). To prevent these mistakes, a user needs to send an email to `####@domain` *instead* of `ticket+####@domain`.

**The Big Question:**

Can I use Procmail to filter emails from `####@domain` to be treated as emails from `ticket+####@domain`?.`.`

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your logic looks like it should work but perhaps I'm reading too much between the lines. Can you show the Subject: line you are trying to parse?

Comment: @tripleee My question is how do I keep users from sending tickets to ticket+####@domain and instead send to ####@domain and handle that within the procmail recipe? One thing I have been experimenting with is modifying the To: field, but I could use some direction. The Subject: line is being parsed because the bug tracker needs the Subject field to follow the format, (Case ####) for the email to forward to the correct entry in the bug tracker.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Procmail doesn't do any address parsing on its own, it simply processes messages which have been routed to this address by your MTA. This sounds vaguely like your actual problem is how to route these messages to Procmail in the first place ...? (Also, tangentially, relying on the `To:` header is not robust; think `Bcc:`.)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer on the `To:` header. I am not experiencing trouble routing these messages to Procmail; I have an address (ticket@domain) that successfully forwards emails sent as ticket+####@domain to our bug tracker for a related entry where ticket = ####. My big question: Is it possible to use Procmail to alter the name of an address format (####@domain) to an existing address (ticket@domain)? The domain host has a Procmail integration which is where I am writing these rules. If this is outside the bounds of what Procmail can do, then that will help me redirect myself.

Comment: Do you mean send to `987543@domain` instead of `ticket@domain`? You don't need to rewrite any headers to do that; just forward to `$MATCH@domain` (or maybe `ticket+$MATCH@domain` if that's what you actually want).

Comment: Yes; let me make sure I'm clear. The idea is I have one address `ticket@domain` where users send emails to create entries in our bug tracker. Currently, a user does this by sending to `ticket+987543@domain`, and the Procmail recipe uses `$MATCH` to grab the ticket number that correlates to the bug tracker entry and forwards accordingly. This works. **What I want to do** is prevent auto-completion errors (a user will enter `ticket+` in the address field and the wrong ticket # is auto-completed). To do this a user needs to send an email to `987543@domain` but follows the _same_ process as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems rather confusing, but what you are asking should be possible simply by changing the last line to `!ticket+$MATCH@domain`.

You should probably also use `^TO_` instead of `^To:.*`.

```
:0
* ^TO_\/[0-9]+@domain
* MATCH ?? ^\/[0-9]+
{
 SUBJECT=`/usr/bin/formail -zx "Subject:"`
 :0fhw
 |/usr/bin/formail -I "Subject: $SUBJECT (Case $MATCH)"
 :0
 !ticket+$MATCH@domain
}
```

I added braces to put the assignment and both actions under the condition, so that you don't do unnecessary work to extract the `Subject:` or forward anything if `MATCH` is not set.

(The parentheses around `[0-9]+` were not doing anything useful, so I took them out. Perhaps also make sure you have a sane `PATH` instead of hard-coding the path to `formail`.)

Parsing the headers for the recipient information is not entirely robust, as [the message could be sent as a `Bcc:`](https://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#bcc). Similarly, this assumes that the recipient system correctly examines the envelope recipient information instead of the headers (though also replacing the recipient headers before forwarding would not be very challenging to add, either).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't upvote your answer yet. I wanted to comment to let it be known that the specific solution to my problem ended up being a separate configuration with the host. I changed the address from ticket@domain to *@domain where the asterisk acts as a wildcard allowing those ticket numbers to be entered. Perhaps this clears up some of my problem as there was a bit of a disconnect in understanding. Regardless, there was helpful information in this answer sorting out what I had in my script that was unnecessary.